# serial port output from 8051 micro is incomplete and reversed

Tags: serial-port, uart, corruption, baud-rate

I'm trying to make a program in the 8051 machine language that allows me to send data from its ROM to the PC in 16-byte chunks asynchronously so that it can do other work at the same time. In this code, I was expecting the following output on my screen:

```
Central station Debug Mode
Testing 115200bps speed mode with 16 byte chunks
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
80x25 screen?
uC to Linux screen test
Working? Yes? Maybe? No?
Test 100% wireless. 115200bps speed
TEST IS NOW FINISHED!
TX TEST OVER WAITING FOR RECEPTION!
```

However, I received much less than that. The output I actually received (according to the screen command in Linux) is the following:

```
OITPECER ROF
!H
```

I look at that text and it makes me think it processed the last 16 bytes whilst skipping one along with the rest of the beginning bytes.

I got both the microcontroller and the PC that I'm testing with both set to 115200 bps in raw mode with 8 data bits, no parity and 1 stop bit, and the power to both devices remained connected during the tests so I can't blame lack of power.

Is there anything I can do to this code to improve it so all text can be outputted correctly?

```
    TXBUFS equ 30h
RXBUFS equ 40h
TXOP bit 7Dh
RXOP bit 7Ch

org 0h
ljmp main

org 23h ;serial INT
  push PSW
  setb RS0 ;all serial functions use bank 1.
  jbc RI,rxdf
  jbc TI,txdf
  exitint:
  clr RS0
  pop PSW
reti


main:
mov SP,#52h
lcall serialinit
ljmp startdebug

;Serial port receive function
;Receiver controls R1 value unless we want to reset local buffer
rxdf:
  cjne R1,#RXBUFS+17,noerx
    clr RXOP
    ajmp exitint
  noerx:
  mov @R1,SBUF
  inc R1
ajmp exitint

;Serial port transmit function
txdf:
  cjne R0,#TXBUFS+17,noetx
    clr TXOP
    ajmp exitint
  noetx:
  mov SBUF,@R0
  inc R0
ajmp exitint

;enable receive
startrx:
  setb RS0
  mov R1,#RXBUFS
  setb RXOP
  clr RS0
ret

;Reset receiver stack
resetget:
  setb RS0
  mov R0,#RXBUFS+17
  clr RS0
ret

;Get byte as A from receiver stack.
getrx:
  setb RS0
  dec R0
  mov A,@R0
  clr RS0
ret

;Reset our stack pointer (to zero bytes on transmitter stack)
resetadd:
  setb RS0
  mov R0,#TXBUFS+17
  clr RS0
ret

;Add byte from A onto our transmitter stack. C=1 if end of stack reached
addtx:
  setb RS0
  dec R0
  mov @R0,A
  cjne R0,#TXBUFS,notxendp
    setb C
    inc R0
    clr RS0
  ret
  notxendp:
  clr C
  clr RS0
ret

;send data
starttx:
  setb TXOP ;set transmit busy flag
  setb RS0
  mov SBUF,@R0 ;send 1st byte right away to trigger interrupt later
  inc R0
  clr RS0
ret

;serial init
serialinit:
  mov TH1,#0FFh ;speed=115kbps
  mov TL1,TH1
  mov PCON,#80h
  mov SCON,#50h
  mov TMOD,#22h ;auto reload for timers
  setb RS0
  mov R0,#TXBUFS+17  ;setup our pointers.
  mov R1,#RXBUFS
  clr RS0
  setb TR1
  setb ES
  setb EA ;enable interrupts
ret

startdebug:
  mov DPTR,#mmenu ;load text
  lcall dprint ;and print it (not working correctly)
sjmp $

;print what's in ROM
dprint:
    lcall resetadd ;reset transmitter pointer
dprint2:
clr A
movc A,@A+DPTR
inc DPTR
jz dexitp ;exit function if character from local ROM is 0h
  lcall addtx ;send byte to transmitter
  jnc nostall
    ;at this point, we made buffer full so do 16-byte transmission
    lcall starttx
    ;and stall until all 16 bytes are transmitted
    txst:
      nop
    jb TXOP,txst
    ;reset transmitter pointer again for next 16 bytes
    lcall resetadd
  nostall:
  sjmp dprint2
dexitp:
  ;do one more round of transmission for remaining characters in transmit buffer
  lcall starttx
  ;and stall again
  txst2:
    nop
  jb TXOP,txst2
  ;and reset
  lcall resetadd
ret

mmenu:
db 'Central station Debug Mode',0Dh,0Ah,0Dh,0Ah
db 'Testing 115200bps speed mode with 16 byte chunks',0Dh,0Ah
db '12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890',0Dh,0Ah
db '80x25 screen?',0Dh,0Ah
db 'uC to Linux screen test',0Dh,0Ah
db 'Working? Yes? Maybe? No?',0Dh,0Ah
db 'Test 100% wireless. 115200bps speed',0Dh,0Ah,0Dh,0Ah
db 'TEST IS NOW FINISHED!',0Dh,0Ah
db 'TX TEST OVER WAITING FOR RECEPTION!',0Dh,0Ah,00h
```

Comment: Does your code work with small strings - is a single character send received correctly? two characters? Does it stop working at, maybe, 16, or 17 characters?

Comment: You appear to have carefully coded your transmit buffer as a stack. A Stack is LIFO: Last In First Out. So if you push "h","e","l","l","o" onto this stack, what comes off first is "o", then "l", "l", "e", "h". There must also be some other problem with sending more than one buffer of data. Strongly suggest that rather than coding something complex which when it doesn't work leaves you not knowing where to start with debugging, you take smaller steps like getting a short string to work - you would have noticed immediately if "hi" came out "ih" - then get 17 characters working, and so on.

Comment: Well, first 16 characters working, then 17. And your code will be easier to read and understand if it is better laid out - good convention for assembler is labels always start in in column 1 and instructions in column 8. Plus, it is a good idea to note in the comment before a function the registers the function expects to use, which it will modify, what the side-effects are. Oh, and use a EQU to give the magic number 17 a name and one place to modify.